# Matching 1st and 2nd columns of first file with 1st column of second file

Tags: perl, awk, sed

Want to compare the first and second column of first file with the 1st column of second file.

I do the following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a) {print $2,$1,$3,$4}' file 1 file 2
```

Result of my Script is

```
3 b 33 44
2 c 44 11
5 d 12 21
```

I got the result for first column only and it does not print the repeated value. I want my output with repeated value also.

File1

```
a c 0.1
a b 0.4
b d 0.1
b a 0.8
b c 0.8
c b 0.7
c a 0.6
c d 0.9
d c 0.3
```

File2

```
b 3 33 44
c 2 44 11
d 5 12 21
```

Expected output:

```
3 b 33 44  5  d 12 21  0.1
3 b 33 44  2  c 44 11  0.8
2 c 44 11  3  b 33 44  0.7
2 c 44 11  5  d 12 21  0.9
5 d 12 21  2  c 44 11  0.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading `file2` before `file1` is more practical.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {
  a[$1]=($2 OFS $1 OFS $3 OFS $4)
  next
}
($1 in a)&&($2 in a) {
  print a[$1],a[$2],$3
}' file2 file1
3 b 33 44 5 d 12 21 0.1
3 b 33 44 2 c 44 11 0.8
2 c 44 11 3 b 33 44 0.7
2 c 44 11 5 d 12 21 0.9
5 d 12 21 2 c 44 11 0.3
```